# How to kill an orphan Terminal process

Tags: shell, terminal, java, gdb

I have a java program that executes several shell files (one by each iteration).
The shell file only has one command, start cross-gdb with a path to a gdbinit file.
The program works fine, but (from NetBeans output window) the java program finishes its work and exits, but the terminal window never closes.
I have tested a lot of commands like confirm off and several quit commands in the sh file, but all of them have not worked.

This is the java code:

```
    ProcessBuilder pbuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator", "-e", "/shell");
         
        try {
            
            Process p = pbuilder.start();
            p.waitFor();  
            p.destroy();
            
  } catch (Exception e) {}
```

And the shell file is:

```
#! /bin/sh

export PATH=gcc-arm-8.2-2019.01-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH
arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb --command=/home/null/Desktop/Gem5/gem5/patch.gdbinit
#kill pgrep -f arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb 
#$kill -9 $(pgrep -f x-terminal-emulator)
#killall /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
```

from the shell code, all the # commands, have not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
ProcessBuilder pbuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/shell");
```

and in the shell script

```
#! /bin/sh

export PATH=gcc-arm-8.2-2019.01-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH
nohup arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb --command=/home/null/Desktop/Gem5/gem5/patch.gdbinit &>/dev/null
```

What `nohup` does is it makes a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Yes, I tried that and it works fine for me. :)